# How do I update the Input box value of Telerik:RadAsyncUpload control?

Tags: telerik

How is the `Input box` portion of the telerik:RadAsyncUpload control updated?

I think it can be done on the telerik:RadUpload control

Unless it is possible they were floating a label of FileName text over the control?

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#fuRadUploadFile2').text('file name');
            });

            function OnClientFileSelected(sender, args) {
                var currentFileName = args.get_fileName();
                alert(currentFileName);
                $('#fuRadUploadfile1').val(currentFileName);
                alert("after");
            }
        </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div id="RadUpload">
        <telerik:RadAsyncUpload runat="server" 
            AllowedFileExtensions=".wav,.mp3,.mpeg,.mpg,.wmv,.avi,.mp4" 
            MaxFileSize="262144000" 
            TargetFolder="\Upload" 
            InputSize="50" 
            ID="fuRadUpload"
            ClientIDMode="Static" 
            OnClientFileSelected="OnClientFileSelected" />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnUploadFile" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/buttons/butUpload.gif" />
    </div>
    <input id="fuRadUploadFile2" type="text" value="text" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not allowed due to security reasons. Only the user is allowed to update the input field when he/she selects a file or manually types the file name.

It cannot be done via server property or javascript.

Imagine you visit site.com and it automatically has the input field filled with c:\users\admin\documents\password.txt - it can trigger a button click to upload that file, meaning every site could eventually upload random files from users' computers.

This is not possible.

Comment: Thanks, but why do they have an input box for a display then? I can add a picture if needed.

Comment: The user can type inside the name of the file to upload, but it cannot be pre-populated from the server.